# Is there anyway to avoid crashing chrome due reaching memory limit for Ext JS Application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, memory-leaks

I'm trying to build Ext JS application which is using websockets. Application primarily meant to run in chrome, at I have noticed memory footprint goes beyond 200+ MB and chrome starts freezing. I have used chrome://memory to check memory usage and do some profile.

However, Is there any way using which I can programmatic-ally detect this situation and avoid crashing of browser.

Comment: @Besnik, Given ExtJS provides ready to use component. we prefer to leverage them instead of re-inventing the wheel to get UI components. I'm interested to programmatically detect the out of memory kind of situation and inform user either to save and exit or wait sometime to get application responding back.

Comment: Even if you detect memory usage there is very little you can do in most cases.

Comment: @Nas I'm just kidding you! :-)

Comment: All [chrome://memory pages are gone](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=588790) now.

Answer (score 0):

Does it freeze as soon as ExtJS loads, or are you actually performing functions for your application when it freezes? It might be that your application is pulling down too much data onto the client, in which case, the culprit is not ExtJS. If you are doing client-size data caching or pagination, make sure you're not loading too much data.

Comment: I guess it's not issue with ExtJS, it could be due to the amount of data loaded + number websockets. However, I'm interested to know if programatically i can detect such condition on runtime somehow.